# Multi-label classification loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, multilabel-classification

I have seen in many places that, for multi-label classification using neural networks, one useful loss function to use is the binary cross entropy for each of the output nodes.

In Tensorflow it looks like this:

```
cost = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()
```

This gives an array with as many values as output nodes we have.

**My question is**, should this cost function be averaged over the number of output nodes? Which in Tensorflow would look like:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits())
```

Or each loss is treated independently?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `N` labels in multi-label classification, it doesn't really matter whether you sum the loss for each class, or whether you compute the average loss using `tf.reduce_mean`: the gradient would point in the same direction.

However, if you divide the sum by `N` (this is what averaging essentially is), this will influence the learning rate at the end of the day. If you are not sure how many labels in the multi-label classification task there will be, it might be easier to use `tf.reduce_mean`, because you wouldn't have to readjust the weight of this loss component compared to other components of the loss, and you wouldn't have to adjust the learning rate in the number `N` of labels changes.

Comment: Okey great, thanks. I know the number of classes, but I'll use tf.reduce_mean anyhow. 
Btw, do you know which metric is used for measuring accuracy in multi-label classification?

Comment: @sdiabr i know keras recommends binary cross entropy

Comment: @sdiabr Maybe [this here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12702/what-are-the-measure-for-accuracy-of-multilabel-data?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) helps?

Comment: @sdiabr specifically keras recommends sigmoid units in the output layer with binary cross entropy loss

Comment: @GrantWilliams If I remember correctly, there should be a unit that combines both the sigmoids and the binary cross-entropy into a single function that can be evaluated in a numerically more robust way. What was its name in `tf` again (they are all called `something_very_long_blah_blah_blah_with_logits`, never can remember which did what without looking it up).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits ?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes, that helps , thanks.
 Thanks for the comments GrantWilliams. Yeah the function you are talking about is the one I mentioned in the question, tf.nn.sigmoid...